# Add custom payload in Prompt (in Action and Parameters section) Dialogflow

Tags: flutter, sdk, dialogflow-es, chatbot, payload

**Query Description:** I am working on a chatbot feature in a flutter app in which I have used Dialogflow SDK to implement the same. *I am dynamically generating UI (Widgets)based on the response of Dialogflow so that user will not have to type everything manually and they can just give the answer by taping on the given options.*

To create the widgets dynamically *I am using Custom payload response* as shown in the image.[image: CustomPayload to create widgets dynamically]

This is working absolutely fine. The problem which I'm getting is, 
**I want to add such custom payload in Prompt type response as shown in below image.**[image: Custom payload in prompt]

> Whatever I am adding in Prompt is not going in payload object. How can
>   I add JSON(custom payload) in Prompt?

Answer (score 2):

Simply try this:

```
{
  "message": "$VegPizzaNames"
}
```